# Writing to a text file within a jar file

Tags: java, jar, outputstream

I was recently trying to export my game to a jar file, and I ran into a problem with converting files to input and output streams. With the regular code that was not exported, I was able to read and write to text files by simply calling the Scanner and PrintStream constructor with the File location. This didn't work inside the jar because apparently these were no longer considered as files. I was able to work around the input stream one by doing this:

```
Scanner infile = new Scanner(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("Resources/leaderboard.txt"));
```

as opposed to,

```
Scanner infile = new Scanner("Resources/leaderboard.txt");
```

And I am trying to utilize PrintStream, but so far I have not found an equivalent function that will take in a String location and return an OutputStream for the PrintStream constructor. Should I use a different method for writing to text files in a jar, is there a function or method of converting it to an OutputStream that I have yet to see, or should I avoid printing to a text file altogether?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't and for practical purposes can't write to a "file" within a jar file. Yes, there are kludges that allow you to get around this, but they shouldn't be implemented. Instead all files that the program might change should be outside of the jar and should be separate files.